# Android listview handling click event

Tags: android, onclick, android-listview

I have a custom list view implemented with Baseadapter. My dataset includes a string and a flag. I need to control the clickable property of each row in that list view based on this flag.. Any help will be greatly appreciated..

Comment: clickable propery of each row? What do you want to implement exactly based on flag?

Comment: If you want to implement Click listener then go through this examples: http://goo.gl/7bl4j , http://goo.gl/psSJY, http://goo.gl/wQAr1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that your dataset is collection of data objects that contains a string and a flag. In that case you can `override` the `isEnabled(int position)` in your base adapter like this

```
public boolean isEnabled(int position){
    return myDataSet.get(position).getFlag();// returning true here will make that item clickable
}
```

Note that i am referring to my data object of the corresponding position.

Answer (score 4):

hi subi you could use this below code for setting the clicklistener....

```
 lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(ClassName.this)); 
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
 { 
      @Override 
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) 
      { 
      } 
 });
```

where the arrayAdapter is your customer class extending baseadapter...
Hope this helps...

Comment: I got click event.. But the real problem is I have to disable some rows based on the flag I set..
Thanks for the interest..

Answer (score 0):

If you want the listview with custom properties try to implement your own customAdapter which extends the BaseAdapter

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private  ArrayList<Generics> allElementDetails;

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Generics> results) {
    allElementDetails = results;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

}
public int getCount() {
    return allElementDetails.size();        
}
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return allElementDetails.get(position);
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.filedialog, null);
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    TextView textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    if(flag==true)
             convertview.setClickable(true) 
     else
             convertview.setClickable(false); 
    return convertView;
}
```

}

now use the listview.setOnItemClickListener to apply the actions i.e functionality that will perform when the clickable view clicked.

I think this may help u....